# undefined variable sub_total. even after defining the variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
include('includes/db.php');
?>
<?php include('functions/functions.php'); ?>

<?php
include('header.php');
?>
<?php
include('topheader.php');
?>
<?php
include('nav.php');
?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.php">Cart</a></li> 

            </ul>  <!--breadcrumb ends--->  
        </div> <!---col-md-12 ends-->

        <div class="col-md-9" id="cart">
            <div class="box">
                <form action="cart.php" method="post" enctype="multipart-form-data">
                    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>  
                    <?php
                    $ip_add = getUserIP();
                    $select_cart = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip_add'";
                    $run_cart = mysqli_query($conn, $select_cart);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
                    ?>

                    <p class="text-muted">You currently have <?php echo $count; ?> items in your cart</p>    
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table  class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">Product</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th colspan="1">Unit Price</th>
                                    <th>Container</th>
                                    <th colspan="1">Delete</th>
                                    <th colspan="2">Sub Total</th>
                                </tr>    
                            </thead> <!--thead ends-->

                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $total = 0;
                                while ($row_cart = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cart)) {
                                    $pro_id = $row_cart['p_id'];
                                    $pro_size = $row_cart['size'];
                                    $pro_qty = $row_cart['qty'];
                                    $get_products = "select * from products where product_id='$pro_id'";
                                    $run_products = mysqli_query($conn, $get_products);
                                    while ($row_products = mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)) {
                                        $product_title = $row_products['product_title'];
                                        $product_img1 = $row_products['product_img1'];
                                        $only_price = $row_products['product_price'];
                                        $sub_total = $row_products['product_price'] * $pro_qty;
                                        $total += $sub_total;
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_img1; ?>"></td>    
                                        <td><a href="details.php?pro_id=$pro_id"><?php echo $product_title; ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pro_qty; ?></td>
                                        <td>&#x20b9;<?php echo $only_price; ?>.00</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $pro_size ?></td>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"></td>
                                        <td>&#x20b9;<?php echo $sub_total; ?>.00</td>
                                    </tr>  <!---tr ends-->
                                <?php } ?>    
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5">TOTAL</th>
                                    <th colspan="2">&#x20b9; <?php echo $total; ?>.00</th>  
                                </tr>    
                            </tfoot> <!--tfoot ends-->
                        </table> <!--table ends-->    
                    </div> <!---table-responsive end-->

                    <div class="box-footer">  
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>Continue Shopping    
                            </a>    
                        </div> <!--pullleft ends--> 

                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="update" value="Update Cart"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>Update Cart </button>
                            <a href="checkout.php" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Proceed to checkout<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>    

                            </a>
                        </div> <!--pullright ends--> 
                    </div>  <!----box footer ends-->
                </form> <!---form ends--> 
            </div> <!---box ends-->  
            <?php

            function update_cart() {
                global $conn;
                if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
                    foreach ($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {

                        $delete_product = "delete from cart where p_id='$remove_id'";
                        $run_delete = mysqli_query($conn, $delete_product);
                        if ($run_delete) {
                            echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            echo @$up_cart = update_cart();
            ?>
            <div class="row same-height-row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="box same-height headline">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Recently Viewed Product</h3>
                    </div> <!----box same-height headline end--> 
                </div>  <!---col-m-3 col-md-6 ends---->
                <?php
                $get_products = "select  * from products order by rand() LIMIT 0,3";
                $run_products = mysqli_query($conn, $get_products);
                while ($row_products = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_products)) {
                    $pro_id = $row_products['product_id'];
                    $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];
                    $pro_price = $row_products['product_price'];
                    $pro_img1 = $row_products['product_img1'];

                    echo "<div class='center-responsive col-md-3 col-sm-6'>
          <div class='product same-height'>
            <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
              <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_img1' class='img-responsive'>
              </a>
              <div class='text'>
              <h3><a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>$pro_title</a></h3>
              <p class='price'>&#x20b9; $pro_price</p>

              </div> 

            </div>
         </div>";
                }
                ?>

            </div>   

        </div> 




        <div class="col-md-3">

            <div class="box" id="order-summary">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3>Order Summary</h3>   
                </div>  <!--box-header ends--> 
                <p class="text-muted">
                    Shipping and additional costs are calulated based on the value you have entered.
                </p>    
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Order Subtotal</td>    
                                <th>&#x20b9;<?php echo $sub_total; ?></th>    
                            </tr>    
                            <tr>
                                <td>Shipping and Handling</td>    
                                <td>&#x20b9;0.00</td>    
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td>Tax</td>    
                                <td>&#x20b9;0.00</td>    
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="total">
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <th>&#x20b9; <?php echo $total; ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>    
                    </table>    <!--table ends-->
                </div> <!---table responsive ends-->    

            </div> <!---box ends-->
        </div> <!----col-md-3 ends--->
    </div> <!--container ends--> 
</div> <!---content ends-->
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

i get undefined variable sub_total even after defining variable subtotal above. Can someone figure out what the problem is?? I have check all curly brackets and semicolen. Due on a project that needs to be submited tomorrow. I am thinking improving the coding later but the basic functionality is not working.

Comment: `$sub_total` is never defined if there are no products in the cart.

Comment: even if there are no products in the cart when i go to cart page i see the error undefined variable under subtotal

Comment: Put `$subtotal = 0;` just under the `$total = 0;` line.

Comment: thanks you solved the error.

Comment: @Phylogenesis mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing  ??